# Nginx rewrite is not working as expected

Tags: nginx, rewrite

I am trying to learn how to use nginx and how to use its rewrite functionality

Nginx seems to be doing the rewrite:

```
2012/03/27 16:30:26 [notice] 16216#0: *3 "foo.php" matches "/foo.php", client: 61.90.22.223, server: localhost, request: "GET /foo.php HTTP/1.1", host: "domain.com"
2012/03/27 16:30:26 [notice] 16216#0: *3 rewritten data: "img.php", args: "", client: 61.90.22.223, server: localhost, request: "GET /foo.php HTTP/1.1", host: "domain.com"
```

but in my access log I am getting the following:

```
61.90.22.223 - - [27/Mar/2012:16:26:54 +0000] "GET /foo.php HTTP/1.1" 404 31 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:11.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/11.0"
61.90.22.223 - - [27/Mar/2012:16:30:26 +0000] "GET /foo.php HTTP/1.1" 404 31 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:11.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/11.0"
```

There is an img.php in the root directory so I am not sure why I am getting a 404 error

Here is  part of the configuration block:

```
rewrite foo.php img.php last;


location / {

        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
}





location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
}


# deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
# concurs with nginx's one
#
location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to provide a complete path (relative to the document root) as the destination:

```
rewrite foo.php /img.php last;
```

Adding the slash before img.php should be sufficient (tested on Nginx 1.0.14/CentOS 6).

Nginx will take the path it generates and, if it starts with http:// will perform a 301 or 302 redirect, and otherwise will append it to the document root. In the latter case, the new path needs to start with a slash.

Additionally, if you only want to match the 'foo.php' in the document root, you should precede that argument with a slash as well (not only is it more specific, but it should be quicker to match):

```
rewrite ^/foo.php$ /img.php last;
```